# Связь между двумя таблицами

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

У меня есть таблица Tovar. В ней есть куча полей

- id
- name
- item_type (тут один товар или группа товаров)
- articul (артикул товара)
- и т.д.

Так же есть таблица Seo. В ней есть поля

- id(тут записан артикул)
- title
- description
- h1
- keywords

Мне нужно сделать связь между Товарами и Seo по артикулу. Но так же в id таблицы Seo есть группа (а не артикул). Эту группу тоже как-то нужно связать с таблицей Tovar. Модельки,собственно, я создал, а вот что использовать пока не понимаю.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас проблема с проектированием БД- не может в одном поле находится и артикул и группа. Может стоит вынести это в 2 отдельных поля?

Comment: как вы отличаете id товара от id группы в таблице Seo?

Comment: Вот я тоже об этом подумал, мне эту таблицу дали, а со связями я никогда не работал

Comment: В общем я сделал связь tovar.seo_tag  и метод, если это группа tovar.seo_group. В методе написал так  `def seo_group
    @_seo_group ||= ->{
      return nil if !group?
      ::Market::Model::Product::SeoTag.find tree_id
    }.call
  end`